# Tech company chat where each question creates an opt-in subchannel for answers / debate

Tags: chat

In my company, we've grown out of four successive enterprise chat platforms (Yammer, Slack, Workplace, WhatsApp). We currently have a WhatsApp group which, despite being restricted to lead developers (~35 people), frequently becomes too active for the productivity of everyone. Questions typically generate dozens of replies, sometimes more than one topic is simultaneously discussed...

We are looking for a enterprise chat system where:

- Each message only notifies those targeted, on their computers and/or phones:

  - for a general question, that would be everybody;
  - for the answers to the question, it would be the person who asked, and whoever opts in for the answer
- All developers may use it (write rights are not reserved to a subgroup)
- Easy to post code.

What I'm thinking is a system where any message generates an opt-in subchannel where the question can be answered or debated among those interested only. EDIT: a bit like a chat version of StackOverflow.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why don't you use Slack (or its open source clone Mattermost) channels? People can create new channels and people who are interested can join.

Comment: We've had Slack for a while. We could go back to it, but we'd need to teach people to always create a channel for any question. I'd rather it was the app's default behaviour. 
The more I think about my ideal solution, the more it sounds like a chat version of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

How about *Trello*?

I know is not meant for that, but you could open cards for each topic and just tag the people who are interested in that topic.

Comment: Interesting idea, as we already use Trello for projects. I think a downside would be that it's less focused on chat, so it would be relatively awkward to use as a chat.